# Weird series of numbers - any logic in it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, computer-science

I have the following table where the first column is an index, the second column has all the powers of 2 raised to i.

I can't understand what does the third column represent. It should be something computer-science related

[image]

Comment: Source: http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat.pdf

Comment: Thank you!! I lost the link and I couldn't find it!

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, the third column is indeed the sequence of prime numbers. Whether or not their is any "logic" to this sequence is still being figured out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third column is the list of prime numbers. $p_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ prime.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) is the best way to answer this kind of question. And, in fact, if you [search for your sequence there](http://oeis.org/search?q=2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53), the first hit is the sequence of prime numbers.

Comment: And I didn't know of this one too, thank you!!